# Find max column value from distinct column values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select multiple max values from rows with different usernames.

**Table:**

```
Username | Score  
x        | 50    
x        | 88    
y        |  77    
y        | 90    
z        | 101    
z        | 94
```

So it'd fetch:

```
x = 88, y = 90, z = 101
```

Here's what I have currently:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score FROM table";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $row['max_score'];
}
```

I want to incorporate the Username column into this so it doesn't just echo the maximum value of the entire table column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is work as your requirement

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score FROM table GROUP BY username";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $row['max_score'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query should be like this,

```
SELECT USER_NAME, MAX(SCORE) 
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY USER_NAME
```